# Extract parts of csv filename in columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, filenames, columns

I have a set of .csv files in a directory, say

```
abc_q1_w1.csv
defg_q11_w2.csv
hijk_q11_w3.csv
```

I want to write a script that extracts parts of the filename and put them in columns, i.e

```
abc     q1      w1
defg    q11     w2
hijk    q11     w3
```

Does anyone know how this kind of filename extraction can be achieved using a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using sed

```
$ printf "%s\n" * | sed 's/.csv$//; s/_/\t/g'
abc     q1      w1
defg    q11     w2
hijk    q11     w3
```

How it works:

- `printf "%s\n" *` prints the file names one per line
- `s/.csv$//` removes the trailing `.csv`.
- `s/_/\t/g` converts the `_` to tabs.

#### Using bash

```
$ for f in *; do f="${f%.csv}"; printf "%s\n" "${f//_/$'\t'}";  done
abc     q1      w1
defg    q11     w2
hijk    q11     w3
```

If it helps with clarity, the above code can be split over multiple lines:

```
for f in *
do
    f="${f%.csv}"
    printf "%s\n" "${f//_/$'\t'}"
done
```

`${f%.csv}` removes the trailing `.csv` and `${f//_/$'\t'}` converts all the `_` to tabs.

We do not use `echo` for this task because, if one of the file names begins with `-`, many shells would try to interpret that file name as an option and the result would not be good.

#### Running the code from a different directory

```
$ for f in "$dir"/*; do f="${f#$dir/}"; f="${f%.csv}"; printf "%s\n" "${f//_/$'\t'}";  done
abc     q1      w1
defg    q11     w2
hijk    q11     w3
```

Comment: thanks but how do i extract the filenames from a directory?( I am doing- for file in $DIR/*.csv; do NAME=$(basename $DIR/*.csv) and then your steps but basename doesnt seem to work.)

Comment: @zsha No problem.  I just added code to the end of the answer to handle reading from other directories.  By the way, it is good practice to use lower or mixed case names for your shell variables.  This way you avoid accidentally clobbering system variables with unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
ls -1 | tr '_' '\t'
```